# How to build a regular expression matching hexadecimal digits?

Tags: java, regex, hex, hexdump

I am trying to create a regex for a Byte sequence. The sequence is the Input-String from the user for example:

```
00 a5 88
```

The regex should check if the Input is a correct Byte sequence. So this for example shouldn't be possible:

```
00 0 66
```

but these two should:

```
a b
a 05 b
```

So far I have this regex:

```
(^[a-fA-F\\d]{1,2})((\\s[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)
```

The problem is the end.

This works fine for `01` or `45 45` or `2` but not for `45 4` or `4 5` or `4 00 55 4`

I tried it with this: `(^[a-fA-F\\d]{1,2})((\\s[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)([a-fA-F\\d]{1,2}$)`

But doesn't work how I thought.

Ihe Input should be hex-Byte because afterwards I am searching for this Input in a dump string which looks like that:

[image: Hexdump screenshot]

This works perfectly for me:

```
BYTE_REGEX = "(^(\\p{XDigit}{1,2}))(\\s\\p{XDigit}{2})*(\\s\\p{XDigit})?";
```

Comment: What does "correct" mean? Why is "00 0 66" invalid but "00 a5 88" valid?

Comment: Have you tried trying to parse Hex? If it fails or is out of bounds, it wasn't a correct sequence ... or is this an assignment on regexes :)

Comment: How about `\p{XDigit}{1,2}( \p{XDigit}{2})*( \p{XDigit})?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex for 128 bytes represented as Hex:

```
^([0-9|a-f|A-F][0-9|a-f|A-F]){1,64}$
```

if you want for X-bytes just put the X/2 value in the regex:

```
^([0-9|a-f|A-F][0-9|a-f|A-F]){1,X/2}$
```

Comment: This will match `||||||||`

Comment: No it doesn't, your regex doesn't match spaces and it matches pipe character, so, it's wrong.

Comment: please test it ;)          `final String a = "This is the corect answer";
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.getBytes().length * 2);
        for (final byte b : a.getBytes()) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        final Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("^([0-9|a-f|A-F][0-9|a-f|A-F]){1,100}$");
        System.out.println(reg.matcher(sb.toString()).find());`

Comment: The provided dump is an example of Hex format i.e Tcp dump. We don't need to validate spaces in the regex...

Comment: Did you read the question? OP wants to match something like `00 a5 88`, your regex doesn't match this.

Comment: if you see my code above you will see that my code is matching real example of Hex String. The provided example "00 a5 88" is dump from some tool. The real value of the string will be "00a588...". Btw the regex will match the Hex string but not `||||` like you mentioned in your first comment!!!

Comment: Where have you seen that the regex must match a real hex dump? I'm sorry but your regex DOES match `||||` , `|` in a character class is really a pipe character.

Comment: This answer is wrong - the pattern matches pipes since they are inside the bracket expression. Temporarily downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should use :

BYTE_REGEX = "(^\s*(\p{XDigit}{1,2}))(\s+\p{XDigit}{2})*(\s+\p{XDigit})?";

It is a slight variation of your own that allows :

- spaces at the beginning of the string (unsure if useful)
- more than one space as delemiter

Because dumps generally display 16 bytes per line by grouped by 4 or 8 with a larger separation between groups.